# Raku - How can a program verify if a module is installed locally

Tags: installation, module, raku

How would I discover whether a Raku module has been installed locally? If some module is not installed, eg. a GUI, then a CLI would be used. Eg.

```
if is-installed('GTK::Simple') { gui-response } else { cli-response };
```

What should be the body of 'is-installed'?

Comment: Fwiw, [a search of SO for "is installed" using `[raku]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+%22is+installed%22). Are any of those helpful/relevant? If so, but they don't cover what you need, please consider editing your question to include links to the best, plus discussion of what you need extra that they don't cover. TIA.

Comment: even more specifically than the search @raiph mentioned, [How can I tell programmatically if a Perl 6 module is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899148/how-can-i-tell-programmatically-if-a-perl-6-module-is-installed) seems to answer this question.  Is there something you're looking for that isn't answered there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
sub is-installed(Str $module-name) {
    try {
        require ::($module-name);
        return True;
    }
    False;
}
```

Check the [documentation for `require`](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#index-entry-require) for more background information.